# Convert bytes received to KB/MB - Android

Tags: android

I use the below code to display Transmitted and received bytes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;
    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
            TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);
            long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
            long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();

        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED
            || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();       
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);  
        }
    }
}
```

**But** I want to add units to it (i.e KB, MB, GB). For example, if the data usage is less than 1MB, it should display in KB and should change to MB and GB respectively.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this code should work for RX:

```
long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes) + " bytes");
if(rxBytes>=1024){
    //KB or more
    long rxKb = rxBytes/1024;
    RX.setText(Long.toString(rxKb) + " KBs");
    if(rxKb>=1024){
        //MB or more
        long rxMB = rxKb/1024;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxMB) + " MBs");
        if(rxMB>=1024){
            //GB or more
            long rxGB = rxMB/1024;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxGB));
        }//rxMB>1024
    }//rxKb > 1024
}//rxBytes>=1024
```

it assumes that totalRX is bytes, and set's text with unit
then goes deeper, and set text if size fulfilled (KB, MB, GB)
if it worked for you, use the same code for TX.

**Note:** if you don't like the multi `setText()` calls
you can declare temp variables, for `size` and `unit` fill them as you go deeper in the `if-statements` then `setText()` one time below main `if-statement`

```
RX.setText(Long.toString(size) + " " + unit);
```

Comment: i have asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528516/calculate-network-speed-from-trafficstats-android

Answer (score 9):

Use this

```
 public static String getFileSize(long size) { 
    if (size <= 0)
     return "0";
     final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
     int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024)); 
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
     }
}
```

Comment: i like your sol, pure math, this is my weak point :), voting up

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a built-in function for this.

```
    size = Formatter.formatFileSize(this, s)
```

This is the complete function:

```
        private fun getFileSize(uri : Uri?) : String {
            var size = "0 KB"
    
            uri?.let { returnUri ->
                contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
            }?.use { cursor ->
                /*
                 * Get the column indeces of the data in the Cursor,
                 * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
                 * and display it.
                 */
                val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                var s =  cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                size = formatFileSize(this, s)
            }
            return size
        }
```

For more info check this: [More Details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter)